# Meaning of embedded keyword in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have seen and used compile, compile files, androidTestCompile etc for importing dependencies in my android project. Today I came across embedded in the gradle of an existing android project. Not sure what this means. Even googling didn't help me on this. Can anyone please help. Below is the line I saw in the build.gradle file.

```
embedded 'com.eyeverify:EVServiceInterface:2.6.1-release@aar'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword `embedded` doesn't exist in `Gradle` syntax. I think in that android project, `embedded` was a custom `configuration` defined in a `build.gradle` file:

```
configurations {
    embedded
}
```

So you can use:

```
embedded 'com.eyeverify:EVServiceInterface:2.6.1-release@aar'
```

Comment: Thats correct. Thanks for the info. I have to do some research now, as I can see that the  configurations {
    embedded
} part is in fat-aar.gradle. Not sure what thats for.